# Инкрементирование итератора в функции

Tags: c++

Имется такой код:

```
auto NextIterator(std::list<Word> const& list, std::list<Word>::iterator iterator)
{
    auto i = iterator; 
    if(i != list.end())
    {
        ++i;
    }

    return i;
}
......
for (auto i = iterator; i != list.end(); ++i)
{
    i = NextIterator(list, iterator);
```

Проблема в том, что в функции NextIterator итератор всегда указывает на первый элемент. Как правильно передать его, что бы он указывал на текущий элемент

Comment: Брр... Вы передаете постоянно в `NextIterator` одно и то тже значение - `iterator` - что вы хотите?... И еще - непонятно, что вы добиваетесь, изменяя `i` в теле цикла, а потом еще и выполняя `++i`? Зачем? даже если бы все равно на следующей итерации `i` не становилось тем же, что и на предыдущей... Может, вы хотели что-то типа `for (auto i = iterator; i != list.end();  i = NextIterator(list, i))`?

Comment: @Harry, я делаю синтаксический анализатор, во всяком случае подобие его, вот как цикл выглядит https://pastebin.com/yRiJvmL8

Comment: Мне нужно функцией NextIterator инкрементировать итератор и проверять, не последний ли элемент это в списке

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю, зачем вам эта функция. Ведь цикл `for (auto i = iterator; i != list.end(); ++i)` *без* нее в теле цикла делает то же самое. Непонятно только, какое у вас начальное значение `iterator`.

Comment: Это прекрасно, но вы же сами каждый раз  передаете туда одно и то же значение.

Comment: @AnT я передаю одно значение, его инкрементирую и возвращаю уже инкрементированное значение, следовательно я не могу передавать одно и тоже значение

Comment: Это утверждение могло бы быть верным, если бы было написано `i = NextIterator(list, i);`

Comment: @Harry у меня есть поток лексем в виде списка (class,test,{,},;). Мне нужно проанализировать это, дохожу до элемента списка "class" и захожу в функцию ClassStmt, и в этой функции продолжаю перебирать элементы. Записал, что тип класс, функцией NextIterator хочу проверить не последний ли это элемент был и если не последний беру следующий элемент

Comment: @VTT тоооочнооо, спасибо большое) весь день убил на это(

Comment: Забавно, что я это (`i = NextIterator(list, i)`) написал вам еще в самом первом комментарии :)

Comment: @Harry действительно, просто в другом контексте был, из-за этого не заметил) Спасибо большое!